# Is a non-empty Language required to contain the empty string by definition?

Tags: formal-languages

If I have some non-empty language $L$, is $\epsilon \in L$ always true by definition? Is there a good place to read about the formal definition of a Language (aside from wikipedia)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the empty string need not be in the language.  A formal language is simply a set of strings over a finite alphabet, with no restrictions on the set.

If you Google "formal language theory" you'll get lots of hits.  I did so, and [this chapter](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/FormalLanguageTheory.pdf) looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answerer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464707/is-the-empty-set-in-every-language), no, even though $\emptyset \subset S$ in set theory, this does not mean that $\epsilon \in L$.